# PHP download click show download code as html in webpage

Tags: php, zend-framework

When i click on my download button on my index page showing the download page code below the button as html and download not working. 
The download page have code to decrypt files and then download.

The code i am using for encryption is zend and it's part is given below.

```
$options = array(
                // Encryption type - Openssl or Mcrypt
                'adapter' => 'mcrypt', 
                // Encryption algorithm
                'algorithm' => 'rijndael-192', 
                'vector' => '236587hgtyujkirtfgty5678', 
                // Encryption key
                'key' => $secret_key 
                );
```

but my code is failing like, it's writing to my index page as html below the download button.But no error message.

```
                'mcrypt', 
                // Encryption algorithm
                'algorithm' => 'rijndael-192', 
                'vector' => '236587hgtyujkirtfgty5678', 
                // Encryption key
                'key' => $secret_key 
                );
```

the code above and it's continuing download code and all the code below this above code is displaying in index page as html.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I was using this earlier and it was working fine.i just added zip file function now and i think it's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your file extensions are in different format other than .php, then you need to configure your web server to treat any strange file extension as it treats files with .php extensions. If you are on Apache, 
changing AddType application/x-httpd-php to
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html might help unless otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. i will try this method.